# Rotas privadas com reactjs?

Tags: react, react-router

Estou tentando criar rotas privadas com o `ReactJs`, mas sempre da o mesmo erro, já fui em vários sites e sempre faço de acordo com o tutorial de cada um, mas ainda sim o mesmo erro continua:

Meu código é o seguinte:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
<Route
  {...rest}
  render={props =>
    isAuthenticated() ? (
      <Component {...props} />
    ) : (
      <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/", state: { from: props.location } }} />
    )
  }
/>);
```

esse já é uma das maneiras que encontrei em um site, o erro que da é o seguinte:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém poderia me ajudar com esse problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu tenho o código dessa forma, percebi que no seu tem um parenteses no lugar das chaves, pode ser isso, só estou supondo, mas, logo abaixo tem o código que utilizo e que funciona perfeitamente, onde `isAuthenticated` é a função que verifica se está logado ou não, exemplo:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Redirect, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

const isAuthenticated = () => localStorage.getItem('token');

export const PrivateRouter = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => {
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={props => 
                    isAuthenticated() ? (
                        <Component {...props} />
                    ) : (
                        <Redirect to={{pathname:"/login", state: {from:props.location}}} />
                    )
                }
        />
    )
}
```

para utilizar:

```js
<PrivateRouter path={''} exact component={component} />
```

Comment: Blz, deu certo aqui, a primeira vista ele não funcionou olhei la o parenteses como vc tinha comentado, mas ainda sim deu erro, então coloquei o isAuthenticated dentro do próprio arquivo como vc colocou ai, então deu certo, obrigado pela ajuda, já estava quebrando cabeça a uns dois dias.